# how do i increase the resolution of my gif file?

Tags: python, matplotlib, python-imaging-library, gif, matplotlib-basemap

As I am trying to create a gif file, the file has been created successfully but it is pixelating. So if anyone can help me out with how to increase resolution.

.**Here is the code:-**

```
import PIL
from PIL import Image
import NumPy as np

image_frames = []
days = np.arange(0, 12)

for i in days:
    new_frame = PIL.Image.open(
        r"C:\Users\Harsh Kotecha\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\totalprecipplot" + "//" + str(i) + ".jpg"
    )
    image_frames.append(new_frame)

image_frames[0].save(
    "precipitation.gif",
    format="GIF",
    append_images=image_frames[1:],
    save_all="true",
    duration=800,
    loop=0,
    quality=100,
)
```

**Here is the Gif file:-**

[image]

**Here are the original images:-**

[image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FK8hm.jpg)

[image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZX6fs.jpg)

[iamge3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oMKZU.jpg)

Comment: What do you mean with "it's pixelating"? The resolution seems fine, but there are dithering artifacts; GIFs are limited to 256 colors per frame, and your source data has more.

Comment: Can you share a couple of frames of the original images please?

Comment: I have edited the post Mark please have a look at it.

Comment: thank you so much for providing the code but there is one thing I want to ask for f string how do I open a file which is having a path.

Comment: And one more thing I wanted to ask where did you learn all these things because I'm a beginner.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Updated Answer**

Now that you have provided some images I had a go at disabling the dithering:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from PIL import Image

# User editable values
method = Image.FASTOCTREE
colors = 250

# Load images precip-01.jpg through precip-12.jpg, quantize to common palette
imgs = []
for i in range(1,12):
    filename = f'precip-{i:02d}.jpg'
    print(f'Loading: {filename}')
    try:
       im = Image.open(filename)
       pImage = im.quantize(colors=colors, method=method, dither=0)
       imgs.append(pImage)
    except:
       print(f'ERROR: Unable to open {filename}')


imgs[0].save(
    "precipitation.gif",
    format="GIF",
    append_images=imgs[1:],
    save_all="true",
    duration=800,
    loop=0
)
```

[image]

**Original Answer**

Your original images are JPEGs which means they likely have many thousands of colours <sup>[2](https://legacy.imagemagick.org/Usage/anim_basics/)</sup>. When you make an animated GIF (or even a static GIF) each frame can only have 256 colours in its palette.

This can create several problems:

- each frame gets a new, distinct palette stored with it, thereby increasing the size of the GIF (each palette is 0.75kB)
- colours get dithered in an attempt to make the image look as close as possible to the original colours
- different colours can get chosen for frames that are nearly identical which means colours flicker between distinct shades on successive frames - can cause *"twinkling"* like stars

If you want to learn about GIFs, you can learn 3,872 times as much as I will ever know by reading Anthony Thyssen's excellent notes [here](https://legacy.imagemagick.org/Usage/anim_basics/), [here](https://legacy.imagemagick.org/Usage/anim_opt/) and [here](https://legacy.imagemagick.org/Usage/anim_mods/).

Your image is suffering from the first problem because it has 12 *"per frame"* local colour tables as well as a global colour table<sup>[3](https://legacy.imagemagick.org/Usage/anim_opt/)</sup>. It is also suffering from the second problem - dithering.

To avoid the dithering, you probably want to do some of the following:

- load all images and append them all together into a 12x1 monster image, and find the best palette for all the colours. As all your images are very similar, I think that you'll get away with generating a palette just from the first image without needing to montage all 12 - that'll be quicker
- now palettize each image, with dithering disabled and using the single common palette
- save your animated sequence of the palletised images, pushing in the singe common palette from the first step above

---

<sup>[2](https://legacy.imagemagick.org/Usage/anim_basics/)</sup>: You can count the number of colours in an image with **ImageMagick**, using:

```
magick YOURIMAGE -format %k info:
```

<sup>[3](https://legacy.imagemagick.org/Usage/anim_opt/)</sup>: You can see the colour tables in a GIF with `gifsicle` using:

```
gifsicle -I YOURIMAGE.GIF
```

Comment: Thank you so much mark for such a detailed explanation.

Comment: @HarshKotecha I have added some code to give you an idea of how I would approach it.